# Python str subclass represents a value which is not a real string

Tags: python, string, class, inheritance, subclass

I am a novice in python. Working on extending an older module. So far it had a function that returned `str` (output of a blocking shell command). Now I need that function to also be able to return an object so later operations can be done on it (checking output for a non-blocking shell command). So the function now returns an instance of my class which I subclassed from `str` for backward compatibility. The problem is, however, when such an object is passed to os.path.isdir - it always returns False, even with the string being a valid path

```
import os


class ShellWrap(str):

    def __new__(cls, dummy_str_value, process_handle):
        return str.__new__(cls,"")

    def __init__(self, dummy_str_value, process_handle):
        self._ph = process_handle
        self._output_str = ""

    def wait_for_output(self):
        # for simplicity just do 
        self._output_str = "/Users"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._output_str)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._output_str)

    def __eq__(self,other):
        if (isinstance(other, str)):
            return other == str(self._output_str)
        else:
            return super().__eq__(self,other)

>>> obj = ShellWrap("",None)
>>> obj.wait_for_output()

>>> print(type(obj))
... <class '__main__.ShellWrap'>

>>> print (ShellWrap.__mro__)
... <class '__main__.ShellWrap'>
   (<class '__main__.ShellWrap'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'object'>)

>>> print(type(obj._output_str))
... <class 'str'>

>>> print(obj)
... /Users

>>> print(obj._output_str)
... /Users
>>> obj == "/Users"
... True
```

The one that puzzles me is :

```
 >>> print(os.path.isdir(obj))
... False **<<-- This one puzzles me**
print(os.path.isdir("/Users"))
... True
```

I tried to add PathLike inheritance and implement one more dunder but to no prevail :

```
class ShellWrap(str,PathLike):
   ....
   def __fspath__(self):
      return self._output_str
```

It seems there is one more **dunder** that I failed to implement. But which?

I do see, however, something strange in the debugger. When I put a watch on `obj` - it says it is of a class `str` but the value is shown by the debugger is without the quotes (unlike other 'pure' strs).
Adding quotes manually to the string in the debugger - makes it work but I guess editing a string probably creates a new object, this time pure str.

What do I miss?

**Edit**: after realizing (see the accepted answer) that what I try to do is impossible, I decided to challenge the decision of having to subclass `str`. *So now my class does not inherit anything*. It just implements `__str__, __repr__ and __fspath__` and this seems to be enough! Apparently as long as the `str` inheritance is there - it gets precedence, the dunders don't get called and it tricks some libraries to go fetch the underlying C storage of the str value

Comment: try `os.path.isdir(str(obj))` , just to see if it works

Comment: @Luka, thanks. I know it works but I can't. I am not allowed to change the code outside of my class. I need to build my class such that it is fully str compatible...

Comment: If you go with PathLike, in `__fspath__` you can `return str(self._output_str)` , no?

Comment: it does not change anything since `>>> print(type(obj._output_str))
... <class 'str'>`

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is impossible.

C code working with a string accesses the *actual string data* managed by the `str` class, not the methods you're writing. It doesn't care that you attached another string to your object as an attribute, or that you overrode a bunch of methods. It's closer to `str.__whatever__(your_obj)` than `your_obj.__whatever__()`, although it doesn't go through method calls at all.

In this case, the relevant C code is the `os.stat` call that `os.path.isdir` delegates to, but almost anything that uses strings is going to use something written in C that accesses the `str` data directly at some point.

You want your object's data to be mutable - `wait_for_output` is mutative - but you cannot mutate the parts of your object inherited from `str`, and that's the data that matters.

Comment: what do you mean _C code working with a string_ - is the fact that `os.path.isdir` implemented in C changes the behavior here ? Where can I read more about it to understand better. Sounds like something that breaks the language if I need to worry how some functions are implemented and whether they honor the language flows .. But I probably miss the big picture here

Comment: And if he inherits a path object and returns a usual python string in the path object functions, whats the issue?

Comment: @LukaKostic: It's not clear what you mean by that, but the question states a requirement that the class inherit from `str`.

Comment: is there any way to spot other functions like that in the future? Is this something common in Python ? It is like a whole different realm taking place in parallel to Python domain.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica right but shouldnt os.path.isdir try to get `__fspath__` and get returned `_output_str` which is just a normal string?

Comment: @LouisShraga: You should pretty much assume that any mismatch between the underlying `str` data and the value you want to represent is going to cause problems. Far too much code is going to go for the underlying `str` data directly.

Comment: wow. any good article to read about? is it just str or all native types?

Comment: @LukaKostic: It happens to various degrees with all built-in types. Lots of weird bugs happen because someone didn't expect built-in code to ignore their `dict` method overrides. That includes [core Python bugs](https://bugs.python.org/issue34320) like `dict.update` ignoring `OrderedDict` order.

Comment: @LukaKostic: You could argue that it should, but that's not what happens, and the design motivation of introducing `__fspath__` didn't include messing with existing `str` behavior.

Comment: @LukaKostic - I did try subclassing from PathLike and implementing `__fspath__` but I did so in multiple inheritances `(str,os.PathLike)`. And so the `str` got precedence, I guess. Subclassing PathLike alone and implementing `__str__,__repr__ and __fspath__ `is something I am going to try to see if it covers my backward str compatibility needs

Comment: @LouisShraga: You don't actually need to subclass `os.PathLike` to implement `__fspath__`. It's not like a Java interface. Anyway, if that works, then your `str` backward compatibility needs were a lot lower than you thought.

Comment: Personally, I would separate the roles here. Instead of having an object whose value suddenly changes after calling `wait_for_output`, I'd have `wait_for_output` store and return an output string. With the current design, there's too much of a risk of clients using the wrong value before the `wait_for_output` call.

Comment: @ user2357112 supports Monica thanks for the suggestions! Since I am pretty new to python I still don't have a good grasp of what is considered "nice" and what is not. Having a function (`shell`) returning obj of one type on some invocations and a str on others - was a doubt for me... Having an obj which changed its value over time seemed like a "less astonishment" approach. So what I actually just did is the `shell` function calling `obj.wait_for_output` on all blocking calls but still return obj (which now has the value).So the older sync calls still get their str-like obj with the str ready

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Consider the source of `os.path.isdir`. When you pass in `obj`, you’re probably triggering that value error because the string you want to evaluate is an attribute of your string subclass, not the string the subclass is supposed to represent. You’ll have to muck around a bit more in the source for `str` to find the right member to override.

Edit: one possible way around this is to use `__init__` dynamically. That is, *get everything you need done to render the path string* in`__new__`, and before you return the class in that method, set `output_str` as an attribute. Now in your `__init__`, call `super().__init__` with `self.output_str` as the only argument.

Comment: Where do you find source code of built in functions?

Comment: There is no "right member to override". `__init__` won't help either - `str` doesn't do anything in `__init__`. It doesn't even have its own `__init__` - it inherits `object.__init__`.

Comment: Getting everything ready in `__new__` would be the way to go, but that would require waiting for output from the shell command, and the question wants object creation to be non-blocking.

Comment: Ok, maybe not `__init__`, but there’s an entrypoint because `str` accepts an argument!

Comment: @LukaKostic that doesn’t seem like a duplicate question as far as I can tell :)

Comment: @will_f mine? Yeah it prolly is, was just asking here so i wouldnt have to search.. :P